# Помогите решить ошибку с запуском бота дискорд

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
import logging
import os
from unicodedata import name

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import __init__  # noqa
import database
from config import config


bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=config["bot"]["prefix"],
    intents=discord.Intents(
        messages=config["bot"]["intents"]["messages"],
        guilds=config["bot"]["intents"]["guilds"],
        members=config["bot"]["intents"]["members"],
        bans=config["bot"]["intents"]["bans"],
        reactions=config["bot"]["intents"]["reactions"],
    ),
    case_insensitive=config["bot"]["case_insensitive"],
    help_command=None,
)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@bot.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    """
    Called when the client is done preparing the data received from Discord.
    """
    log.info(f"Logged in as: {str(bot.user)}")

    # TODO: Apparently changing presence in on_ready is bad practice and can result in connection interruption?
    await bot.change_presence(
        activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=config["bot"]["status"])
    )

    # TODO: Move this to an admin command rather than running every time the bot loads.
    # await bot.register_commands()

if name == "main":
    for cog in glob.iglob(os.path.join("cogs", "*", "[!^_].py"), root_dir="chiya", recursive=True):
        bot.load_extension
    database.Database().setup()
    bot.run(config["bot"]["token"])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Предоставьте код, по одной ошибке нельзя сказать, что у вас не так

Comment: можете дать телеграм? просто там очень много папок с кодами и в них скакают ошибки, могу скинуть вам?

Comment: Мне не нужны файлы с кодом, отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте туда код, где ошибка...

Comment: можете смотреть, поменял код